# Generating xml from database in spring boot java

Tags: java, xml, spring, stax

I want to generate/marshall a stream/collection of java objects that I got from a table via jpa query to an xml. I am processing these java objects and converting them to xml in batches. I want to know which of these would perform better and scale better in case the size of the xml grew in future:
 1. STAX 
 2. JAXB
 3. XSTream

Or is there any other api that convert java objects to xml which perform better? I tried looking through all these but could only find the examples of unmarshalling/converting the xmls to java objects.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use JAXB, i have tried with xml very huge and it works perfectly.

This would be and example of marshalling a Object to a String.

The `namespace` is a `Map` where I have the mapping between the class and the `.xsd` pertinent

```
private String marshallXml(Object request, Class<?> clazz) {

        try {

            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz);
            Marshaller marshaller = null;

            if (context != null) {
                marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
                marshaller.setProperty("jaxb.noNamespaceSchemaLocation", namespacesMap.get(clazz));
                StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                marshaller.marshal(request, sw);
                return sw.toString();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }

    return null;
}
```

Example of the `Map`:

```
Map<Class<?>, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(MyClass.class,"http://urlWhereTheXSDisUploaded/MyClass.xsd");
```